# How to expand a dataframe with a tree structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tree

I have a data frame, which has an embedded tree structure inside it, like this:

df1

```
     Category  Type    Dependent-Category
 0    1         ~       A
 1    1         ~       B
 2    1         ~       C
 3    1         ~       14
 4    1         ~       D
 5    1         P       NaN       
 6    A         ~       C
 7    A         ~       D
 8    A         ~       3
 9    A         P       NaN
 10   B         ~       D
 11   B         ~       C
 12   B         ~       12
 13   B         P       NaN
 14   C         ~       D
 15   C         ~       9
 16   C         P       NaN
 17   D         ~       12
 18   D         ~       3
 19   D         ~       8
 20   D         P       NaN
```

Category D rows are only made out of numerical categories, which is defined as.

```
D         ~       12
D         ~       3
D         ~       8
D         P       NaN
```

Category C rows are made out of a numerical Category and the previous Category D, which is defined as:

```
C         ~       D
C         ~       9
C         P       NaN
```

Category B are made out of a numerical Category and the previous 2 Categories D and C, which is defined as:

```
B         ~       D
B         ~       C
B         ~       12
B         P       NaN
```

Category A are made out of a numerical Category and the previous 2 Categories C and D, which is defined as:

```
A         ~       C
A         ~       D
A         ~       3
A         P       NaN
```

Category 1 are made out of a numerical Category and the previous 4 Categories A,B,C and D, which is defined as:

```
1         ~       A
1         ~       B
1         ~       C
1         ~       14
1         ~       D
1         P       NaN
```

The aim is to get a final dataframe which has is a total concatenation of all the Categories - for example, when `Category` A is mentioned in the `Dependent-Category` column in df1, I need to replace that entire row with `Category` A.

The aim is to make the `Dependent-Category` column only consist of numbers (and NaNs):

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution can be to separate out different categories as dataframes and then merge them sequentially with original dataframe then apply conditional formatting.

Here is my solution doing the same:

```
d = {
    "Category": [1, 1, 1, 1, "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"],
    "Type": ["~", "~", "~", "P", "~", "~", "P", "~", "P"],
    "D_C": ["B", "A", 14, "missing", 4, "B", "missing", 12, "missing"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df_A = df.loc[df.Category == "A"]
df_B = df.loc[df.Category == "B"]

df1 = df.merge(df_A, left_on=df.D_C, right_on=df_A.Category, how="outer")

df1_A = pd.DataFrame()

df1_A["Category"] = np.where(
    df1.D_C_x == df1.Category_y, df1.Category_y, df1.Category_x
)
df1_A["Type"] = np.where(df1.D_C_x == df1.Category_y, df1.Type_y, df1.Type_x)
df1_A["D_C"] = np.where(df1.D_C_x == df1.Category_y, df1.D_C_y, df1.D_C_x)

df2 = df1_A.merge(df_B, left_on=df1_A.D_C, right_on=df_B.Category, how="outer")

df_final = pd.DataFrame()

df_final["Category"] = np.where(
    df2.D_C_x == df2.Category_y, df2.Category_y, df2.Category_x
)
df_final["Type"] = np.where(df2.D_C_x == df2.Category_y, df2.Type_y, df2.Type_x)
df_final["D_C"] = np.where(df2.D_C_x == df2.Category_y, df2.D_C_y, df2.D_C_x)

print(df_final)
```

Let me know if you have questions around it.

Comment: The order is not correct for df_final

Comment: You can sort it to get the desired order

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using graph theory.

The advantage is that you do not need to worry about the depth of the mappings (e.g., B->A->C->D would be tricky, even worse if you have circular paths).

You have the following directed graph:

[image]

You can use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) to generate your graph from the part of your DataFrame that has a dependent category, and to map the childrens automatically:

```
import networkx as nx

# split the DataFrame in twao parts
# df1 will contain the rows with a dependent category
# df2 will contain the rows with the values
# using here a regex to identify letter but any other logic can be used
m = df['Dependent-Category'].str.match('[a-zA-Z]+').fillna(False)

df1 = df[m]
df2 = df[~m]

# generating the graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                            source='Dependent-Category', target='Category')

# keep only nodes with children
nodes = set(filter(G.out_degree, G.nodes))
# {'A', 'B'}

# mapping nodes to children and self
d = {n: (nx.descendants(G, n)&nodes)|{n} for n in nodes}
# {'A': {'A'}, 'B': {'A', 'B'}}

# replacing the values in the DataFrame 
df3 = (df1['Dependent-Category']
 .map(d).explode()
 .to_frame('Category')
 .reset_index()
 .merge(df2)
 .set_index('index')
)

# merging the above df3 to df2
out = pd.concat([df2, df3]).sort_index(kind='stable')
```

output:

```
  Category Type Dependent-Category
0        A    ~                  4
0        A    P                NaN
0        B    ~                 12
0        B    P                NaN
1        A    ~                  4
1        A    P                NaN
2        1    ~                 14
3        1    P                NaN
4        A    ~                  4
5        A    ~                  4
5        A    P                NaN
5        B    ~                 12
5        B    P                NaN
6        A    P                NaN
7        B    ~                 12
8        B    P                NaN
```

##### edited example

[image]

output:

```
   Category Type Dependent-Category
0         A    ~                  3
0         A    P                NaN
1         B    ~                 12
1         B    P                NaN
2         A    ~                  3
2         A    P                NaN
2         B    ~                 12
2         B    P                NaN
2         C    ~                  9
2         C    P                NaN
3         1    ~                 14
4         A    ~                  3
4         A    P                NaN
4         B    ~                 12
4         B    P                NaN
4         C    ~                  9
4         C    P                NaN
4         D    ~                 12
4         D    ~                  3
4         D    ~                  8
4         D    P                NaN
5         1    P                NaN
6         A    ~                  3
6         A    P                NaN
6         B    ~                 12
6         B    P                NaN
6         C    ~                  9
6         C    P                NaN
7         A    ~                  3
7         A    P                NaN
7         B    ~                 12
7         B    P                NaN
7         C    ~                  9
7         C    P                NaN
7         D    ~                 12
7         D    ~                  3
7         D    ~                  8
7         D    P                NaN
8         A    ~                  3
9         A    P                NaN
10        A    ~                  3
10        A    P                NaN
10        B    ~                 12
10        B    P                NaN
10        C    ~                  9
10        C    P                NaN
10        D    ~                 12
10        D    ~                  3
10        D    ~                  8
10        D    P                NaN
11        A    ~                  3
11        A    P                NaN
11        B    ~                 12
11        B    P                NaN
11        C    ~                  9
11        C    P                NaN
12        B    ~                 12
13        B    P                NaN
14        A    ~                  3
14        A    P                NaN
14        B    ~                 12
14        B    P                NaN
14        C    ~                  9
14        C    P                NaN
14        D    ~                 12
14        D    ~                  3
14        D    ~                  8
14        D    P                NaN
15        C    ~                  9
16        C    P                NaN
17        D    ~                 12
18        D    ~                  3
19        D    ~                  8
20        D    P                NaN
```

Comment: many thanks. I'm new to networkX, how would I do it for 4 categories (the example I gave was for 2 categories, A & B)? What tweaks would I need to do the code?

Comment: please edits for 4 categories. This is the problem I am facing. Please use the exact same method you used for 2 categories, thanks

Comment: @User112211 it should work for any number of categories without changing anything, see updated output

Comment: Thanks @mozway for pointing towards this approach. Also good to learn something new.

Comment: @mozway, many many thanks. For some reason, the script is not working for my actual data. Can I email the data to you? I know how the final output df should be as I had done it manually to verify.

Comment: You can maybe provide a link? best would be to try to generate a minimal example for which it doesn't behave as expected (and clearly explaining how it fails)

Comment: @mozway, and yes will buy you a coffee :)

Comment: Great! I'll have a look

Comment: do you maybe have a smaller (minimal) example of a case where it produces an incorrect result? Here is the [complete graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yaxE.png), not easy to do potential debug ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245301/discussion-between-user112211-and-mozway).